# Using OR in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've looked [through the docs](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html) and I cant seem to find out how to do an OR query in SQLAlchemy. I just want to do this query.

```
SELECT address FROM addressbook WHERE city='boston' AND (lastname='bulger' OR firstname='whitey')
```

Should be something like

```
addr = session.query(AddressBook).filter(City == "boston").filter(????)
```

Answer (score 534, accepted):

From the [tutorial](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators):

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
filter(or_(User.name == 'ed', User.name == 'wendy'))
```

Comment: Note that this approach supports using generators, so if you have a long list of things to OR, you can do `filter(or_(User.name == v for v in ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Carl')))`

Comment: @Robru's advice is unnecessarily inefficient. If you already have a collection then you should use the `in_` operator like this: `filter(User.name.in_(['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carl']))`

Comment: Ah thanks i was not aware sqlalchemy had that filter

Comment: @intgr The example showed by robru is still efficient, if you want to use another operator instead of in_, for example the LIKE operator.

Comment: @intgr My experience with Oracle shows that a sequence of "OR"s is way faster than using "IN". Also "IN" is limited to a set of ~1000 entries, while "OR" is not.

Comment: @g.a Using `OR` when you have a list of values to compare against a single column (i.e., exactly what `IN` does) might be fairly premature optimization, let the query analyzer optimize it for you. Also you can get very different results with other RDBMs. Even for Oracle I doubt that the statement is true in general, there are for sure scenarios when using `IN` is faster/more efficient.

Comment: @robru Thanks a lot! It solve the problem: ```query.filter_by(**somedict)``` when the type of somedict's value is ```list```.The code is:```query.filter(getattr(Classname,somedict'key)==v for v in somedict'value)```

Answer (score 478):

SQLAlchemy overloads the bitwise operators [`&`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_), [`|`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_) and [`~`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.not_) so instead of the ugly and hard-to-read prefix syntax with `or_()` and `and_()` (like in [Bastien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7942571/298479)) you can use these operators:

```
.filter((AddressBook.lastname == 'bulger') | (AddressBook.firstname == 'whitey'))
```

Note that the parentheses are **not optional** due to the precedence of the bitwise operators.

So your whole query could look like this:

```
addr = session.query(AddressBook) \
    .filter(AddressBook.city == "boston") \
    .filter((AddressBook.lastname == 'bulger') | (AddressBook.firstname == 'whitey'))
```

Comment: +1, but could you instead wrap the last two filter arguments in more parentheses and use an `&` between them and the first (rather than using a second `filter` call) for the same effect?

Comment: @ChaseSandmann: Yes you could. But would it be more readable? No.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work if one operand is a collection, but and_() does. E.g. `select(Author).outerjoin(Book, Author.books & (Book.pub_year  == '2020')`

Answer (score 60):

`or_()` function can be useful in case of unknown number of OR query components.

For example, let's assume that we are creating a REST service with few optional filters, that should return record if any of filters return true. On the other side, if parameter was not defined in a request, our query shouldn't change. Without `or_()` function we must do something like this:

```
query = Book.query
if filter.title and filter.author:
    query = query.filter((Book.title.ilike(filter.title))|(Book.author.ilike(filter.author)))
else if filter.title:
    query = query.filter(Book.title.ilike(filter.title))
else if filter.author:
    query = query.filter(Book.author.ilike(filter.author))
```

With `or_()` function it can be rewritten to:

```
query = Book.query
not_null_filters = []
if filter.title:
    not_null_filters.append(Book.title.ilike(filter.title))
if filter.author:
    not_null_filters.append(Book.author.ilike(filter.author))

if len(not_null_filters) > 0:
    query = query.filter(or_(*not_null_filters))
```

Comment: Can this be used with the `==` operator on a column? I see like, ilike etc implemented but no "equals", apart from the `__eq__` override which apparently just returns a bool, not a filter that i can put into `or_()`.

Comment: Umm, no you don't need to write such convoluted logic. You can always collect your conjunctions in a temporary variable. I.e. instead of collecting them in an array you set a variable to False (initially) and `|=` your additional conditions to it.

Answer (score 32):

For SQLAlchemy ORM 2.0 both `|` and `or_` are accepted.

[Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#conjunctions)

```py
from sqlalchemy.future import select
from sqlalchemy.sql import or_


query = select(User).where(or_(User.name == 'ed', User.name == 'wendy'))
print(query)

# also possible:

query = select(User).where((User.name == 'ed') | (User.name == 'wendy'))
print(query)
```

Answer (score 4):

This has been really helpful.
Here is my implementation for any given table:

```
def sql_replace(self, tableobject, dictargs):

    #missing check of table object is valid
    primarykeys = [key.name for key in inspect(tableobject).primary_key]

    filterargs = []
    for primkeys in primarykeys:
        if dictargs[primkeys] is not None:
            filterargs.append(getattr(db.RT_eqmtvsdata, primkeys) == dictargs[primkeys])
        else:
            return

    query = select([tableobject]).where(and_(*filterargs))

    if self.r_ExecuteAndErrorChk2(query)[primarykeys[0]] is not None:
        # update
        filter = and_(*filterargs)
        query = tableobject.__table__.update().values(dictargs).where(filter)
        return self.w_ExecuteAndErrorChk2(query)

    else:
        query = tableobject.__table__.insert().values(dictargs)
        return self.w_ExecuteAndErrorChk2(query)

# example usage
inrow = {'eqmtvs_id': eqmtvsid, 'datetime': dtime, 'param_id': paramid}

self.sql_replace(tableobject=db.RT_eqmtvsdata, dictargs=inrow)
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you need to apply an **or** condition if a condition is met filters can be stored in variable and chained them with a pipe. Here is an example

```
 class Student(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = "student"
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String, nullable=False)

   def get_by_name(self, name):
      condition = # Code Here for condition
      filters = (Student.name == "Stack") | (Student.name == "Overflow") if 
condition else (Student.name == "Stack")
      query = Student.query.filter(filters).order_by(Student.id.asc())
```