# Using OR in SQLAlchemy ORM query

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have some sql queries I'm trying to run as `sqlalchemy.orm.query` objects and I'm wondering if there is a way to use OR.  I can use AND by adding commas into the filter statement but I don't know how to do an OR.  Example code below:

```
query = MyTable.q.filter(MyTable.id == some_number)
```

However I don't know how to do a query with an OR

```
query = MyTable.q.filter(MyTable.id == some_number OR MyTable.id == some_other_number)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Duplicate question, please refer to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942547/using-or-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import or_

query = MyTable.q.filter(
        or_(MyTable.id == some_number, MyTable.id == some_other_number)
    )
```

Of course, there's no point in this case since you can solve it with `in_`.

```
query = MyTable.q.filter(MyTable.id.in_([some_number, some_other_number])
```