# TypeError when doing "ilike or ilike" in an SQLAlchemy filter expression

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to search for users by matching on both first name and last name fields.

In plain SQL I would do:

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE (first_name ILIKE 'pattern') OR (last_name LIKE 'pattern');
```

I'm trying the following with SQLAlchemy:

```
User.query().filter(User.last_name.ilike(pattern) \
                    or User.first_name.ilike(pattern))
```

I get the following error: `TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined`

In the same context, combining two exact matchings (`==`) by `or` would work, so I infer that my issue is related to `ilike` being somehow uncompatible with the `or` operator.

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942547/using-or-in-sqlalchemy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `or` in this way with SQLAlchemy. It has it's own `or_` function:

```
query.filter(or_(expr1, expr2))
```

In specific:

```
User.query().filter(or_(User.last_name.ilike(pattern),
                        User.first_name.ilike(pattern)))
```

The same is true for `and_`, `not_` and `in_` (and possibly more). I *think* you can do something like `expr1 | expr2` but I am not sure.