# mysql sqlalchemy keywords search

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have array with keywords:

```
keywords = ["word1","word2","word3"]
```

and i have table of items:

**items:**

- id
- title
- date

i want find any record that has a title inside the title field

so i want to mix between like("%{word}%".format(word=word))
and "OR"

note that there is other fields so i cant simply make or between all of them i want this to be AND with the the other conditions but unable to figure out how to mark them as a group of OR but AND with the others

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using OR in SQLAlchemy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942547/using-or-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my examples I assume your model is defined as below:

```
class Item(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    date = Column(Date)
```

To build `OR` condition for your keywords, you can use [`or_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_):

```
>>> keywords = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
>>> keywords_condition = or_(*[Item.title.like('%{}%'.format(keyword)) for keyword in keywords])
>>> keywords_condition
'item.title LIKE :title_1 OR item.title LIKE :title_2 OR item.title LIKE :title_3'
```

Then you can use [`filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) method to apply this condition + any amount of others. They will be joined with `AND`:

```
>>> Session.query(Item).filter(keywords_condition, Item.date == date.today())
'SELECT item.id AS item_id, item.title AS item_title, item.date AS item_date 
FROM item 
WHERE (item.title LIKE :title_1 OR item.title LIKE :title_2 OR item.title LIKE :title_3) AND item.date = :date_1'
```