# Flask SQLAlchemy filter by value OR another

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask project that interacts with `MySQL` db through `Flask-SQLAlchemy`.

My question is, how to select a row from the database based on a value OR another value.

#### The results I want in SQL looks like this

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=email OR name=name;
```

How to achieve that in `Flask-SQLAlchemy`?

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942547/using-or-in-sqlalchemy) might give you what you're looking for.

Comment: This is SQLAlchemy, I want that in Flask-SQLAlchemy. I tried to
`from flask_sqlalchemy import or_` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The following may help:

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'url_or_path/to/database'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))

    def __init__(self, name=None, email=None):
        if not name:
            raise ValueError('\'name\' cannot be None')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('\'email\' cannot be None')
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

class UserQuery(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_user_id_by_email_or_name(email=None, name=None):
        user = User.query.filter((User.email == email) | (User.name == name)).first()
        return user.id if hasattr(user, 'id') else None
```

The '|' can be used inside a filter instead of 'or_'. See [Using OR in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942547/using-or-in-sqlalchemy).

You can use like this:

```
>>> from app import db, User, UserQuery
>>> db.create_all()
>>> user = User(name='stan', email='stan@email.com')
>>> db.session.add(user)
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> by_name_id = UserQuery.get_user_id_by_email_or_name(name='stan')
>>> by_email_id = UserQuery.get_user_id_by_email_or_name(email='stan@email.com')
>>> by_name_id == by_email_id
True
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I can not find it. Also does it support `&` for and?

Comment: @SaurabhShrivastava yes,  bitwise operators `&`, `|` and `~` overload the corresponding filter expressions `and_` (which is the default logic join type, therefore only valuable as code clarification), `or_`, and `not_`. See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html.

Answer (score 9):

I also needed this case today, I found the nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7942571/14457833):

So, we can make **OR** logic like the below example:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
db.session.query(User).filter(or_(User.email=='useremail@example.com', User.name=="username")).first()
```

When using the `filter()` expression, you must use proper comparison operators, whereas `filter_by()` uses a shortened unPythonic form.

Comment: I don't think `filter_by` is unpythonic. If anything it seems much more pythonic to me to use kwargs to check values

Answer (score 6):

I also wanted to have an `or` along with `and` condition

I found this after googling around:

```
# Users whose age is 23 AND (firstname IS alex OR lastname IS watson)
usrs = session.query(User) \
    .filter(User.age === "23") \
    .filter((User.firstname == 'alex') | (User.lastname == 'watson')) \
    .all()
```

hopefully, it helps other people coming here looking for it

Answer (score 1):

The question is very old, the answer here is for flask 2.x and flask-sqlalchemy 3.0.x

`db.session.query` is now called *legacy query interface*.  they ask you to instead use `db.session.execute`

if you are following miguel grinbergs mega flask tutorial and your code is looking something like this:

```
orders = Order.query.filter_by(supplier_id=company_id, status="Sent").all()
```

the way to add an `or` in the `where` would be something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_

orders = db.session.execute(
    db.select(Order)
    .where(Order.supplier_id == company_id)
    .where(or_(Order.status == "Sent", Order.status == "Accepted"))
).scalars()
```

here `db` is the `flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy` instance.  `Order` is a `db.Model` derived class.

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/queries/

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that, it does not allow to use filter_by with '|' condition, at least with python 2.x. You will see "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". For ex:

```
Rule.query.filter_by((is_active=True) | (id=rule_id))
```