# What am I doing wrong with or_() in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am creating a search bar where users can enter keywords such as movie title, imdb id, year of release to find a list of matching movies. I have a tabel called Movie looks something like this:

```
id  title   year    runtime rating
tt1490017   The Lego Movie  2014    100 7.8
tt0111161   The Shawshank Redemption    1994    142 9.3
tt0068646   The Godfather   1972    175 9.2
```

I have a query that looks for movies containing the keyword(s) entered by the user that looks like this:

```
movies = db.session.query(Movie).filter_by(or_(id=searchkey,title=searchkey,year=searchkey))
```

where `searchkey` is whatever is entered by the user in the search bar. However when I run this, it gives me the error saying that `TypeError: or_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'`. Did I mess up my syntax or is there something else wrong? Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: According to, e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942547/using-or-in-sqlalchemy) you want to write something like `or_(Movie.id == searchkey, Movie.title == searchkey, Movie.year == searchkey)`. `or_` takes conditions as positional parameters it takes no keyword parameters

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Thanks for the response but in that example, `filter()` was used and for filter(), for every conditional Movie.x, there must be `filter(or_(Movie.x == y, Movie.x == z))` . It doesn't work if its `filter(or_(Movie.x == y, Movie.a == b))` .

Comment: I don't think you can do this using `filter_by`. `filter_by` is a convenience method to be used when you have a simple filter on **one** field. See [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128505/whats-the-difference-between-filter-and-filter-by-in-sqlalchemy) question that shows that you should use `filter` to use `or_`.

Comment: I see, Thanks for the help, I'll try and figure out what I did wrong then since it still doesn't work.