# SQLAlchemy - Search entire DB model columns for a pattern

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a database which I need to return any value that matches the query or looks similar.

Using `flask-sqlalchemy` I can filter manually, but I'm having trouble getting a list of objects using list comprehensions or any other more pythonic method.

I have already tried to create a dict with all model columns (which I have a list ) and the search value passed to the `filter_by` query

```
column_dict_and_value = {column_name:'value' for column_name in columns}    
a = model.query.filter_by(**column_dict_and_value).all()
```

...but doesn't even return an existing object, although

```
a = model.query.filter_by(column_name='value').all()
```

actually returns the object.

I tried `filter(.like('%'))` and it sort of works

```
a = model.query.filter(model.column_name.like('valu%')).all()
```

returns me a list of all the objects that matches that pattern but for that column, and I want to iterate over all columns. Basically a full blown search since I'm not sure what the user is going to look for and I want to show the object if the query exist on any column or a list of objects if the query is incomplete, like the * in any search.

I tried to use list comprehensions to iterate through the model attributes but I'm not allowed to do that apparently:

```
a = [model.query.filter(model.column.like('valu%')) for column in columns]
```

...this complains that column is not an attribute of the model, which makes sense due to the syntax, but I had to try anyway, innit?

I'm a newbie regarding databases and class objects so please be gentle. I tried to look for similar answers but I can't find the one that suits me. the `filter_by(one_column, second_column, etc)` doesn't look to me very pythonic and if for any reason I change the model i need to change the query too where as creating a dict comprehension of the model seems to me more foolproof.

### SOLUTION

Based on `calestini` proposed answer I wrote this code that seems to do the  trick. It also cleans the list because if `all()` doesn't have any result (since it looks in every field) it returns None and adds up to the list. I'd rather prefer it clean.

**Note**: All my fields are text. Please check the third proposed solution from calestini if yours differ. Not tested it though.

```
columns = [
"foo",
"bar",
"foobar"
]


def list_everything(search):
    d = {column: search for column in columns}
    raw = [
        model.query.filter(getattr(model, col).ilike(f"{val}%")).all()
        for col, val in d.items()
    ]
    return [item for item in raw if item]
```

I'll keep optimizing and update this code if I come with a better solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: May not be a dupe but at least this can get you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942547/using-or-in-sqlalchemy. Also, have not tried this yet but found an interesting link for filters https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-filters/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably the reason why you are not getting any result from

```py
a = model.query.filter_by(**column_dict_and_value).all()
```

is because `filter_by` is testing for direct equality. In your case you are looking for a pattern, so you will need to loop and use `filter` as opposed to `filter_by`.

Assuming all your columns are `String` or `Text` types, you can try the following:

```py
a = model.query

for col, val in column_dict_and_value.items():
   a = a.filter(getattr(model, col).ilike(f'{val}%')) #ilike for case insensitive

a = a.all()
```

### Or vs And

The issue can also be that in your case you could be testing for `intersection` but expecting `union`. In other words, you are returning something only if the pattern matches in **all** columns. If instead you want a result in case **any** column matches, then you need to tweak the code a bit:

```py
condition = or_(*[getattr(model, col).ilike(f'{val}%') for col, val in column_dict_and_value.items()])

a = model.query.filter(codition).all()
```

Now if you actually have other data types among the columns, then you can try to first verify if the column type and then pass the same logic:

```py
for col, val in column_dict_and_value.items():
    ## check if field python equivalent is string
    if isinstance(class_.__table__.c[col].type.python_type, str):
       ...
```

Comment: I can't make your code to work fine, the first one doesn't find anything aswell and the second "condition" throws a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. Haven't tried the third way since all my fields are strings since i don't need to operate with the data, just show it. I feel like I'm getting there but it's frustrating...

Comment: I'm not marking it as accepted since I can't make run your code and I'm not sure it is correct. It might be though. Please double check and I'l accept.

Comment: Apologize @jose, I haven't actually run your code, let me try to run a flask app and correct the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @JoseRodriguez Fixed the line, it was missing the `items()` from to unpack the dictionary.