# How to get query in sqlalchemyORM также

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have few form fields on search page. After performing the search, my page should display a list of possible matching results. If the user typed in only part of a title, ISBN, or author name, search page should find matches for those as well. Also if user typed only one or few field - page should show all matches.

Idk how to write query. If i have one value from request.form and other values is None - so whole query is empty

```
@app.route('/search', methods=("GET", "POST"))
def search_book():
    books = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        isbn = request.form['isbn']
        title = request.form['title']
        author = request.form['author']
        year = request.form['year']
        books = db.query(Books).filter_by(isbn=isbn, title=title, author=author, year=year).all()
    return render_template("search.html", books=books)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.filter_by(multiple arguments) will default to AND, meaning the user will have to enter data that matches **all** fields

This also means that if the user leaves fields empty, the query will only return books that have (for example) title = " " (when title form is empty), despite having entered a valid year.

This is probably not intended, from a user point of view. A way to fix this is to (1. validate input data, and then) add filters to a list if they are not empty, then add the non-empty fields using or_(*filter_list). Query will then return all rows that match any field specified by the forms.

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
query = db.query(Books)
filter_list = []
if request.form['isbn']:
    filter_list.append(Book.isbn.ilike(request.form['isbn']))
if request.form['author']:
    filter_list.append(Book.author.ilike(request.form['author']))
# etc...

if len(filter_list) > 0:
    query = query.filter(or_(*filter_list))
```

didnt test code but *filter_list allows you to pass a list to the filter method, or_ allows you to change the default AND to OR

more here:
[Using OR in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942547/using-or-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'or_()' method . This will search all the matching results for any given column

```
name = request.form.get('res')
result = Books.query.filter(db.or_(Books.author==name , Books.isbn==name , Books.title==name)).all()
```

'res' is the search entry given by the user in the search form in your html page , as mentioned it can be anything ISBN , title or the author's name