# select unique values not containing characters a-f from table column with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, select, sqlalchemy

The database table `objects_tbl` has a column object_id, that contains identifier strings that either consist of digits 0-9 only **or** that may additionally contain "hex-digits", i.e. the letters `a-f`. Using SqlAlchemy, I want to select all distinct values from this column which consist of the digits 0-9 only, so I added a condition on the column to not contain a or b or c or d or e or f:

```
col = objects_tbl.c.object_id
query = select([col]).where(not_(or_(col.contains('a'), col.contains('b'), col.contains('c'),
                            col.contains('d'), col.contains('e'), col.contains('f')))).distinct()
```

Within the faculties of SqlAlchemy, is there a more elegant/more concise way to accomplish this without having to list each of the six characters explicitly? The solution should be as little database-specific as possible, so using raw SQL with regular expressions is probably not a good option. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generators inside OR operator like this:

```
or_(col.contains(s) for s in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'))
```

or:

```
or_(col.in_(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']))
```

I've not tried these ways, but this advice is in [Using OR in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942547/using-or-in-sqlalchemy)