# Booleans operators behavior

Tags: python, t-sql, sqlalchemy

*Edit: There was an error in my queries after this selection. Leaving here because the answer is interesting regardless.*

---

I want to create a filter for MS SQL Server like:

```sql
WHERE ((this IS NOT NULL) or (that IS NOT NULL))
```

I tried with the replies [given at a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942547/using-or-in-sqlalchemy):

```py
filter((TAB1.c.this.isnot(None)) | (TAB2.c.that.isnot(None)))

filter(or_(TAB1.c.PERSONNE_ID.isnot(None), (TAB2.c.PERSONNE_ID.isnot(None)))
```

but with those options I can only get:

```sql
WHERE (this IS NOT NULL or that IS NOT NULL)
```

and in T-SQL this is a different filter from the one I want to obtain.

Any hints?

Comment: In what way are the WHERE statements different? Aren't the inner `()` in the first snippet simply not needed thanks to the operator precedence?

Comment: Not sure. Indeed it's also strange to my eyes, but if I test them in SQL queries they give different results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two `WHERE` clauses are identical due to `IS NOT NULL` having a higher operator precedence than `OR` and therefore being evaluated first before the `OR` gets evaluated.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c0e9d/7

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  this INT,
  that INT
);
INSERT INTO test (id, this, that) VALUES (1, 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO test (id, this, that) VALUES (2, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO test (id, this, that) VALUES (3, NULL, 4);
INSERT INTO test (id, this, that) VALUES (4, 5, 6);
```

resulting in

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE ((this IS NOT NULL) or (that IS NOT NULL));
SELECT * FROM test WHERE (this IS NOT NULL) or (that IS NOT NULL);
SELECT * FROM test WHERE (this IS NOT NULL or that IS NOT NULL);
SELECT * FROM test WHERE this IS NOT NULL or that IS NOT NULL;
```

all returning the rows 1, 3 and 4, omitting only item 2 which has both values as `NULL`.